# Setting LineStyleParameters in MicroStation VBA

Tags: vba, microstation

I was originally planning to ask this question on the Bentley forums for programming as they had [a similar answer for a C# question](http://communities.bentley.com/products/programming/microstation_programming/f/343173/t/79820) which I was using to model mine on. However, the account I created for the forums doesn't seem to be working.

The purpose of the code is to set the linestyle, color, lineweight and then lastly two settings which are classified under Line Style Parametra and known as Scale and Corner Mode.

As background, I'm far more familiar with C# than VBA and that might be causing me to miss something, but the solution that I have feels similar to the C# approach highlighted in the link above (which I very serendipitously found):

```
Private Sub AdjustStyleToByLevel(lvlName As String)

' Set up level definitions
Dim oLevel As Level
Set oLevel = ActiveDesignFile.Levels(lvlName)

' Set up scan criteria
Dim oScanCriteria As ElementScanCriteria
Set oScanCriteria = New ElementScanCriteria

oScanCriteria.ExcludeAllLevels
oScanCriteria.IncludeLevel oLevel

Dim oEnumerator As ElementEnumerator
Set oEnumerator = ActiveModelReference.Scan(oScanCriteria)

Dim oElement As Element

Do While oEnumerator.MoveNext
    Set oElement = oEnumerator.Current

    If oElement.IsTraversableElement Then
        Dim oLineElement As LineElement
        Set oLineElement = oElement

        Set oLineElement.LineStyle = ByLevelLineStyle
        oLineElement.Color = ByLevelColor               ' -1
        oLineElement.LineWeight = ByLevelLineWeight     ' -1

        ' Define and set the Line Style settings
        Dim oParams As LineStyleParameters
        Set oParams = oElement.GetLineStyleParameters

        oParams.ScaleFactor = Share.ChartScale / 100
        oParams.SetRunThroughCorners

        oLineElement.SetLineStyleParameters (oParams)
        oLineElement.Rewrite
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

It's the line `oLineElement.SetLineStyleParameters (oParams)` that gives me the error 438: 'Object does not support this method or property'. However, when comparing this to the C# approach mentioned above (quoted below), I fail to notice a major difference.

```
public void ChangeLineStyleScale()
{
    BCOM.Application msApp = BMI.Utilities.ComApp;
    BCOM.LineElement oLine = msApp.ActiveModelReference.GetElementByID64(15092) as BCOM.LineElement;
    BCOM.LineStyleParameters lsParams = oLine.GetLineStyleParameters();
    lsParams.ScaleFactor = 2.0;
    oLine.SetLineStyleParameters(lsParams);
    oLine.Rewrite();
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here, or how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer was provided by Jan Slegr](http://communities.bentley.com/products/programming/microstation_programming/f/53220/p/117839/362841#362841) on Bentley forums to which I finally got access.

> Parenthesis are not used in VBA if a method is called without set =, so you have to remove them:

```
oLineElement.SetLineStyleParameters oParams
```